# Can I access the error signals at particular nodes using automatic differentiation in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have already figured that I can obtain a zipped list of variables and gradients using `compute_gradients`, which I suppose corresponds to `∂E/∂θ`, where `θ` is a variable entry. Is there also a way to access the error signals for particular nodes, e.g. how they are usually defined as `∂E/∂a`, where `a` is the activation, e.g. the affine transform of the input `Wx + b`, or do I need to implement my own back-propagation algorithm in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get errors with respect to activations by including activations in `xs` parameters of `tf.gradients`. IE

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32)
a = x*x
E = 2*a
(dEda, dEdx) = tf.gradients(E, xs=[a, x])
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([dEda, dEdx], feed_dict={x: 1})
```

You should see

```
[2.0, 4.0]
```